React Material ToggleButton Counting
I created a script in React with UIMaterial and set different ToggleButtonGroups. the goal is that the user can answer questions with yes and no. I want to count the "yes" and "no" clicked toggles.
function App() {

const [Q1, setQ1] = React.useState('Q1');
const [Q2, setQ2] = React.useState(() => ['Q2']);

const handleQ1 = (event, newQ1) => {
  if (newQ1 !== null) {
    setQ1(newQ1);
  }
}
  
const handleQ2 = (event, newQ2) => {
  if (newQ2.length) {
    setQ2(newQ2);
  }
}

<label>Question 1</label>
<ToggleButtonGroup value={Q1} exclusive onChange={handleQ1} aria-label="text">
<ToggleButton value="yes" aria-label="left" >Yes</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton value="no" aria-label="right" >No</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>

<label>Question 2</label>
<ToggleButtonGroup value={Q2} exclusive onChange={handleQ2} aria-label="text">
<ToggleButton value="yes" aria-label="left">Yes</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton value="no" aria-label="right">No</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
}

I just could count one question. But I want to count all.

To count the Yes and No across multiple instances of the ToggleButtonGroups, you have to maintain state to keep track of these counts, Using states you would easily update them whenever the button is clicked
You can follow the following implementation:
import React from 'react';
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup';

function App() {
  const [Q1, setQ1] = React.useState(null);
  const [Q2, setQ2] = React.useState(null);
  const [yesCount, setYesCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [noCount, setNoCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleQ1 = (event, newQ1) => {
    if (newQ1 !== null) {
      // Decrement count if the previous answer was yes or no
      if (Q1 === 'yes') setYesCount(yesCount - 1);
      if (Q1 === 'no') setNoCount(noCount - 1);

      // Update the answer and increment count 
      setQ1(newQ1);
      if (newQ1 === 'yes') setYesCount(yesCount + 1);
      if (newQ1 === 'no') setNoCount(noCount + 1);
    }
  };

  const handleQ2 = (event, newQ2) => {
    if (newQ2 !== null) {
      // Decrement count if the previous answer was yes or no
      if (Q2 === 'yes') setYesCount(yesCount - 1);
      if (Q2 === 'no') setNoCount(noCount - 1);

      // Update the answer and increment count 
      setQ2(newQ2);
      if (newQ2 === 'yes') setYesCount(yesCount + 1);
      if (newQ2 === 'no') setNoCount(noCount + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Question 1</label>
      <ToggleButtonGroup value={Q1} exclusive onChange={handleQ1} aria-label="question 1">
        <ToggleButton value="yes" aria-label="yes">Yes</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="no" aria-label="no">No</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>

      <label>Question 2</label>
      <ToggleButtonGroup value={Q2} exclusive onChange={handleQ2} aria-label="question 2">
        <ToggleButton value="yes" aria-label="yes">Yes</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="no" aria-label="no">No</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>

      <div>
        <p>Yes count: {yesCount}</p>
        <p>No count: {noCount}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

This approach should help you to keep track of the Yes & No responses for each of your questions

Many thanks! That works now.
